# What allows all 3 states of H₂O to be present at the same time?

Tags: water, gas-laws, solid-state-chemistry

How is it possible for there to be a glacier floating on water but under clouds? Depending on the temperature, shouldn't there only be one state of water?

Comment: just to clarify. clouds are liquid water in very small droplets (or sometimes very small ice crystals). otherwise you wouldn't be able to see them.

Answer (score 4):

At the [**triple-point**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point) of a substance, all three phases can be present. Since it takes additional energy to go from ice at 0 C to liquid water at 0 C, there can be a considerable overlap for the **two** substances, e.g. 1 g ice with 99 g water or 99 g ice with 1 g water, but for thermodynamic equilibrium, the *triple point* is very narrow.

BTW, the first well-know American chemist, Josiah Willard Gibbs, pioneered in defining the relationship of temperature, pressure and state. See  [Gibbs' phase rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_phase_rule) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're at water's triple point (273.16 K, and a vapor pressure of 611.73 Pa), you must have fewer than three phases **if all phases are in equilibrium**.

However, it's easy to have ice, water, and water vapor present simultaneously under other conditions **if the phases are not all in equilibrium with each other.**

*Note: Water has other triple points, but they involve multiple forms of ice.*